# Userdata in Powershell - Unable to change attached volume permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I am using a cloudformation template to spin up an EC2 instance which uses a Windows Server 2012 R2 AMI. In the template itself, i have also attached and mounted an EBS volume.

In order to allow the disk to be brought online and create a volume automatically, i have written some powershell commands and placed it into UserData section. However, what didn't work is that i am unable to use the command below to modify the permission of the attached volume (D drive). For instance, i am unable to let everyone have the modify permission using icacls.

> "icacls D: /grant everyone:M"

Any pointers on what I am doing wrong would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is is possible that you are running this command too early before the disk is actually mounted? Try adding a 10-second delay before this command and see if the problem still persists. To simulate a sleep on cmd, you can use:
`ping 127.0.0.1 -n 10 > nul`

Comment: i thought so too but even after simulating a 10 seconds sleep as per suggestion, it still doesn't work for the permissions.

Comment: Does the person runing the scripts have permission to modify file permissions on that drive? (is he/she owner?)

Comment: yes. The person running the scripts has the administrative rights to modify the permission on that drive. It requires to run as Administrator to be able to successfully execute this command. Unfortunately, i would like to automate this task but seems unsuccessful.